# Validar se o INSERT foi executado com sucesso ou não (JTDS)

Tags: java, android, sql

Gostaria de saber uma forma de validação pra saber se o insert foi executado com sucesso, não tenho a mínima noção de como fazer isso porque o método execute() não retorna nada!!!

```
Connection connInsert = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
PreparedStatement inserir = connInsert.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO PRODUTO (ID, NOME, QTDE) VALUES (varId, varNome, varQtde)");
inserir.execute();
```

Apenas queria saber validar porque se deu erro ao inserir gostaria de dar a opção de tentar novamente!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O correto para usar o `INSERT`, `UPDATE` e `DELETE` seria o método [`executeUpdate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29), no qual retorna um valor do tipo inteiro. O método [`execute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute%28%29) funciona para `CREATE TABLE` ou `ALTER TABLE` e retorna `false` ou `true`. Veja abaixo como de fato deve ficar seu código:

```
PreparedStatement inserir = connInsert.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO PRODUTO (ID, NOME, QTDE) VALUES (varId, varNome, varQtde)");
int result = inserir.executeUpdate();

if(result > 0){
   // produto inserido com sucess
} else {
   // erro ao inserir produto.
}
```

Comment: eu preciso executar o "inserir.execute()" antes do laço if?

Comment: @MarcioVieira desculpe, acabei me atrapalhando. Veja agora se esclarece pra você.

Comment: Boa, resolvido o problema.... Obrigado =D

Answer (score 1):

Você pode trocar o `execute()` por `executeUpdate()` e testar o valor de retorno. Conforme a documentação oficial:

> int executeUpdate() throws SQLException
>
> Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as
>   INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing,
>   such as a DDL statement.
>
> Returns:
>
> either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing
>
> Throws:
>
> SQLException - if a database access error occurs; this method is called on a closed PreparedStatement or the SQL statement returns a
>   ResultSet object
>
> SQLTimeoutException - when the driver has determined that the timeout value that was specified by the setQueryTimeout method has
>   been exceeded and has at least attempted to cancel the currently
>   running Statement

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()

Answer (score 1):

Faça o seguinte:

```
Connection connInsert = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
PreparedStatement inserir = connInsert.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO PRODUTO (ID, NOME, QTDE) VALUES (varId, varNome, varQtde)");

if(inserir.executeUpdate() > 0) {
    // inserido com sucesso
} else {
    // erro ao inserir
}
```

De acordo com a documentação do [`executeUpdate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()) retornará 1 caso a inserção for bem sucedida e 0 caso não seja possível. Lembrando ainda que você deve tratar as exceções `SQLException` e `SQLTimeoutException` que irão ser lançadas pelo método.

Utilizar  somente `execute()` não é viável neste caso, pois é necessário verificar seu retorno.